# Alertmanager: how to receive alert only during a time interval

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I would like to receive alert (from Opsgenie) only between monday to friday at 9:00 to 18:00

So I did something like that in alertmanager.yml

```
route:
    - receiver: "opsgenie-horsprod"
      group_by: ["hostname", "alertname"]
      matchers: [ severity=CRITICAL, alertname="VM Down" ]
      repeat_interval: 1h
      group_wait: 0s 
      group_interval: 1s 
      continue: true
      mute_time_intervals:
        - specific_hour
        - week_time_no_alert
...
time_intervals:
- name: "specific_hour"
  time_intervals:
  - weekdays: ['monday:friday']
    times:
    - start_time: "18:00"
      end_time: "09:00"

- name: "specific_hour"
  time_intervals:
  - weekdays: ['sathurday:sunday']
    times:
    - start_time: "00:00"
      end_time: "00:00"
...

  - name: "opsgenie-horsprod"
    opsgenie_configs:
      - api_key: "xxx"
        api_url: https://api.eu.opsgenie.com/
        send_resolved: true
```

So it is working fine when I am removing mute_time_intervals but I put it back : I am not receiving any alert on Opsgenie :/

Can you help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just updated alertmanager to the latest version and it is working now .. :)

Comment: User answered himself, suggested the changes that works for him